Planning a single goal with two hardware interfaces with different Joint Trajectory Controllers
Using ROS2 Humble
I am adding a prismatic joint to the base of the UR5e, and I have successfully combined the URDFs to make a new model.
However, I didn't realize until after writing the drivers for my prismatic joint's motor that the UR5 only supports position control. I have adapted a new Joint Trajectory Controller to drive the prismatic slider using a velocity interface, and I have successfully configured my launch to assign the velocity-commanded controller to the prismatic joint while loading the regular position-commanded controller for the rest of the UR5 joints.
Unfortunately, I didn't think about whether I could group these controllers together with a singular goal. Is this possible? Maybe through MoveIt? If it is possible, I would greatly appreciate you can offer some resources/documentation on how to do this.

JTC from ros2_controllers does not support this out of the box. Depending on your needs, you could write a node with two action clients for the two controllers, and maybe wrap that in an service/action server server.
